# Pandas: convert type of column

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column

```
                                         category  
0          [Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Интернет/Универсальное/ ]  
1   [/Рубрики/Бизнес/Недвижимость/Базы недвижимост...  
2   [] 
3   [/Рубрики/Бизнес/Недвижимость/Базы недвижимост...  
4          [Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Интернет/Универсальное/ ]  
5   [] 
6          [Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Интернет/Универсальное/ ]  
7   [/Рубрики/Бизнес/Недвижимость/Базы недвижимост...  
8          [Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Интернет/Универсальное/ ]  
9   [/Рубрики/Бизнес/Недвижимость/Базы недвижимост...  
10         [Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Интернет/Универсальное/ ]  
11  [/Рубрики/Бизнес/Недвижимость/Базы недвижимост...  
12  []  
13  [/Рубрики/Бизнес/Недвижимость/Базы недвижимост...  
14         [Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Интернет/Универсальное/ ]
```

There are lists in column. I need to get first string from every list, but some of lists are empty and when I try to use

```
df.category.iloc[0]
```

I get

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

How can I fix that error and get strings instead of lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df.category = df.category.str[0]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': [['aw','be'],[],['tr','yt','uy'],['tre']]})
print (df)
       category
0      [aw, be]
1            []
2  [tr, yt, uy]
3         [tre]

df.category = df.category.str[0]  
print (df)
  category
0       aw
1      NaN
2       tr
3      tre
```

If need replace `NaN` with empty string:

```
df.category = df.category.str[0].fillna('')
print (df)
  category
0       aw
1         
2       tr
3      tre
```