# Convert pandas column from object type [] in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have read this [Pandas: convert type of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765187/pandas-convert-type-of-column) and this [How to convert datatype:object to float64 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277137/how-to-convert-datatypeobject-to-float64-in-python)
I have current output of df:

```
Day       object
Time      object
Open     float64
Close    float64
High     float64
Low      float64
                 Day          Time   Open  Close   High    Low
0      ['2019-03-25']  ['02:00:00']  882.2  882.6  884.0  882.1
1      ['2019-03-25']  ['02:01:00']  882.9  882.9  883.4  882.9
2      ['2019-03-25']  ['02:02:00']  882.8  882.8  883.0  882.7
```

So I can not use this:

```
day_=df.loc[df['Day'] == '2019-06-25']
```

My final purpose is to extract df by filtering the value of column "Day" by specific condition.
I think the reason of df.loc above failed to excecute is that dtype of Day is object so I can not execute df.loc
so I try to convert the above df to something like this:

```
               Day       Time   Open  Close   High    Low
0      2019-03-25  ['02:00:00']  882.2  882.6  884.0  882.1
1      2019-03-25  ['02:01:00']  882.9  882.9  883.4  882.9
2      2019-03-25  ['02:02:00']  882.8  882.8  883.0  882.7
```

I have tried:

```
df=pd.read_csv('output.csv')
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

#df['Day'] = df['CTR'].str.replace('[','').astype(np.float64)
df['Day'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Day'].str.replace(r'[,.%]',''))
```

But it does not work with error like this:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "['2019-03-25']" at position 0
```

I am novice at pandas and this may be duplicated!
Pls, help me to find solution. Thanks alot.

Comment: Start with `df = df.replace([r"\['", r"'\]"], ['', ''], regex=True)`, then do as you please.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works as my expectation.

Comment: You're welcome! I recommend deleting your question as it is quite an esoteric issue (mostly an issue of incorrectly saving or loading your data). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope it would work 
first remove list brackets by from day then do filter using .loc

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Day':[['2016-05-12']],
                       'day2':[['2016-01-01']]})

df['Day'] = df['Day'].apply(''.join)
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day']).dt.date.astype(str)

days_df=df.loc[df['Day'] == '2016-05-12']
```

**Second Solution**
If the list is stored as string

```
from ast import literal_eval
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Day':["['2016-05-12']"],
                       'day2':["['2016-01-01']"]})
df2['Day'] = df2['Day'].apply(literal_eval)
df2['Day'] = df2['Day'].apply(''.join)
df2['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Day']).dt.date.astype(str)
days_df=df2.loc[df2['Day'] == '2016-05-12']
```

Comment: sorry, that does not work. The result of day_ is an empty df as what I have tried

Comment: so i added a dataframe that I used and it worked on this dataframe

Comment: @cs95 can you explain how it is wrong ?, I have run this code and it is working

Comment: You're wrong in your assumption that the column is a list of strings.

Comment: @cs95 now I have updated the solution, taking  list as  i.e "['2016-01-01']" .kindly check it again